# What could cause a shiny app to freeze in Chrome but not in Safari?

Tags: javascript, r, google-chrome, shiny, shinydashboard

I've built a ShinyApp / Shiny Dashboard (hosted on an internal shiny server at my company). It's worked perfectly fine for over a month, but, as of today, is freezing on Google Chrome. It continues to work fine in Safari. Any thoughts on why this could be? My early guess is that Chrome is shutting down because it's asked to load what it considers to be too much data from the server, but I don't know if that's indeed the case.

And, fwiw, I've tried to use chrome's developer console to find something informative, but the page freezes before any insightful info can be displayed that way.

Thanks in advance!

-Lucas

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ShinyApp in particular, but there have been recent (June 2016) reports of Chrome's JavaScript engine freezing and/or running very slowly.
I wonder if you're experiencing the same issue.

See this thread on the Chrome support forum: [Chrome JS engine very slow + freezes since last versions](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/6XMuPTejwzE;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/authorid$3AAPn2wQf-OGy-4X629Dv0LWZL-wRFkplZRdbqlTfe0kGV2avDD6mP0WU7GnU8bKpw3MTJ_NrDPBEI%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false) .

Comment: This may be the culprit. Some supporting evidence: my app is running as expected in Chrome Canary Version 54.0.2788.0 canary (64-bit), but is not working in Chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

If you are using Firebug Firefox, you'll notice the problem from time loading of JavaScript files so you have to make JavaScript files call firstly by put them inside main page or before the code script .
or you can use getscript() method .